# use shorthand condition in parameter

Tags: c#

I have a method that takes a nullable int as a parameter :

```
myMethod(int? parameter) {
//body
}
```

and, in the method that calls this method, the parameter I will pass can obviously either be a null or an int (but its a string first). What I'm trying to do is the following:

```
myMethod(
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(someString)?
    Convert.ToInt32(someString) : null
);
```

however I'm getting an error :

> type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and null

Comment: @PeterRitchie sorry I had carrots <  and > but they weren't showing up

Comment: The world would have been such a nicer place if `Nullable<T>` existed in C# 1.0 and as a consequence `TryParse` could simply return an `int?`.

Comment: @Servy is that a sarcastic way of saying I should just use TryParse?

Comment: @AbdulAhmad Well, you should, but no, that's not what I was saying.  It was saying `TryParse` is poorly designed (in light of language features now available; too bad the C# devs don't have time machines to fix this problem).  There should be a TryParse that returns an` int?`, and if there were, the solution to your problem would be trivial, and you wouldn't have had to ask a question about it.

Comment: @Servy I see, yes it would be!

Comment: @Servy If they wanted to, the .NET devs could certainly add a `TryParse` that takes a single argument and returns a `Nullable<int/double/etc.>`. We're also free to write our own trivial implementations of it.

Comment: @JLRishe Creating your own is certainly an option.  I do so myself for most instances where I would need to use either method.  While it's technically possible for such methods to be added to .NET, practical considerations make doing so...difficult, although not impossible.  I certainly wouldn't ever expect to see them be added.

Comment: I wish I knew why I have a down vote.. this is a legit question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast one side to `int?`

```
 !string.IsNullOrEmpty(someString)
  ? Convert.ToInt32(someString)   
  : (int?)null
```

Answer (score 3):

You want the value of the conditional operator that you're using to evaluate to an `int?`, but **neither the second nor their operands are of type `int?`**.  Both of them are implicitly convertible to `int?`, but when C# needs to determine the type of an expression, given choices A and B as options, it will *always choose A or B*, and not type C that happens to have implicit conversions from A and B.

As for what to do, simply cast either of the last two operands to type `int?`.  (It doesn't matter which one.)